# SQL Search for missing record, then insert value

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, select, sql-insert

Below is a very oversimplified problem I am trying to solve

I have the following tables:

```
**quiz**

id   title  
--------------
1   first
2   second
3   third
4   fourth
5   fifth

**quiz_status**

id   status   user_id   quiz_id 
-------------------------------
1      0         1         1
2      0         1         2
3      0         1         3
```

if a I run the following:

```
select * 
from quiz as q
left join quiz_status as qs
ON q.id = qs.quiz_id 
where qs.user_id=1
```

I'd get:

```
id   title  id   status   user_id   quiz_id
-------------------------------------------
1   first   1      0         1         1
2   second  2      0         1         2
3   third   3      0         1         3
4   fourth  null   null      null      null
5   fifth   null   null      null      null
```

**I would like to be able to insert values where missing/null in the quiz_status table.**

so the final outcome would be:

```
id   title  id   status   user_id   quiz_id
-------------------------------------------
1   first   1      0         1         1
2   second  2      0         1         2
3   third   3      0         1         3
4   fourth  4      0         1         4
5   fifth   5      0         1         5
```

What would be the insert statement for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the `insert ... select` syntax:

```
insert into quiz_status(status, user_id, quiz_id)
select 0, u.user_id, q.id
from (select distinct user_id from quiz_status) u
cross join quiz q
left join quiz_status qz on q.id = qz.quiz_id and u.user_id = qz.user_id
where qz.quiz_id is null
```

This works by generating all combinations of users and quizs, and then `left join`ing the status table to filter on missing records. In the real life, you would likely have a `users` table that you can use in place of the `select distinct` subquery.

If you need just one user it's simpler:

```
insert into quiz_status(status, user_id, quiz_id)
select 0, 1, q.id
from quiz q
left join quiz_status qz on q.id = qz.quiz_id and qz.user_id = 1 
where qz.quiz_id is null
```

Note: presumably, `id` is a serial column so I left it apart in the `insert`s.